# How to get the index facilities of each element in a list flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter,I ran into a problem.I need to specify

```
Facilities facilities = facilitiesList[index];
```

But I have an error on the word index. I'm passing the list into a list view builder. Please find my code below and this the error:

```
"message": "A value of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Facilities'.\nTry changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Facilities'.",
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:oracle_diamond_02/model/facilities.dart';
import 'package:oracle_diamond_02/screen/facilities_details_screen.dart';

class FacilitiesListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  FacilitiesListScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  _FacilitiesListScreenState createState() => _FacilitiesListScreenState();
}

class _FacilitiesListScreenState extends State<FacilitiesListScreen> {
  final TextStyle dropdownMenuItem =
      TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18);

  final primary = Color.fromARGB(255, 206, 84, 84);
  final secondary = Color(0xfff29a94);

  final List<Map> facilitiesList = [
    {
      "name": "Badminton Court",
      "location": "UTM Convention Hall",
      "type": "Indoor Courts",
      "logoText":
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/badminton.jpg?alt=media"
    },
    {
      "name": "PingPong Court",
      "location": "UTM Convention Hall",
      "type": "Indoor Courts",
      "logoText":
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/pinpong.jpg?alt=media"
    },
    {
      "name": "Futsal Court",
      "location": "UTM Convention Hall",
      "type": "Indoor Courts",
      "logoText":
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/futsal.jpg?alt=media"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tennis Court",
      "location": "UTM Convention Hall",
      "type": "Outdoor Courts",
      "logoText":
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/tennis.jpg?alt=media"
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xfff0f0f0),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 145),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: facilitiesList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        Facilities facilities = facilitiesList[index];
                        Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                            onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        FacilitiesDetailsScreen(facilities)));
                          },
                        ));
                        return buildList(context, index);
                      })),
              Container(
                height: 140,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: primary,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.menu,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "List of Facilities",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.filter_list,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 110,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      child: Material(
                        elevation: 5.0,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                        child: TextField(
                          // controller: TextEditingController(text: locations[0]),
                          cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          style: dropdownMenuItem,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Search Facilities",
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black38, fontSize: 16),
                              prefixIcon: Material(
                                elevation: 0.0,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                                child: Icon(Icons.search),
                              ),
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 25, vertical: 13)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 110,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              border: Border.all(width: 3, color: secondary),
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(facilitiesList[index]['logoText']),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  facilitiesList[index]['name'],
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: primary,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.location_on,
                      color: secondary,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(facilitiesList[index]['location'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: primary, fontSize: 13, letterSpacing: .3)),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.sports_tennis,
                      color: secondary,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(facilitiesList[index]['type'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: primary, fontSize: 13, letterSpacing: .3)),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code of `Facilities` class.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different `facilitiesList`. One in `FacilitiesListScreen` and one in `Facilities` (as a global variable). By declaring another one in `FacilitiesListScreen` the other one went out of scope, but it seems you wanted to use that one in some part. Renaming it maybe solves your problem, for example to `facilitiesListMap`. Try out this code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:oracle_diamond_02/model/facilities.dart';
import 'package:oracle_diamond_02/screen/facilities_details_screen.dart';

class FacilitiesListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  FacilitiesListScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  _FacilitiesListScreenState createState() => _FacilitiesListScreenState();
}

class _FacilitiesListScreenState extends State<FacilitiesListScreen> {
  final TextStyle dropdownMenuItem =
      TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18);

  final primary = Color.fromARGB(255, 206, 84, 84);
  final secondary = Color(0xfff29a94);

  final List<Map> facilitiesListMap = [
    {
      "name": "Badminton Court",
      "location": "UTM Convention Hall",
      "type": "Indoor Courts",
      "logoText":
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/badminton.jpg?alt=media"
    },
    {
      "name": "PingPong Court",
      "location": "UTM Convention Hall",
      "type": "Indoor Courts",
      "logoText":
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/pinpong.jpg?alt=media"
    },
    {
      "name": "Futsal Court",
      "location": "UTM Convention Hall",
      "type": "Indoor Courts",
      "logoText":
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/futsal.jpg?alt=media"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tennis Court",
      "location": "UTM Convention Hall",
      "type": "Outdoor Courts",
      "logoText":
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/tennis.jpg?alt=media"
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xfff0f0f0),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 145),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: facilitiesList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        Facilities facilities = facilitiesList[index];
                        Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                            onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        FacilitiesDetailsScreen(facilities)));
                          },
                        ));
                        return buildList(context, index);
                      })),
              Container(
                height: 140,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: primary,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.menu,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "List of Facilities",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.filter_list,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 110,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      child: Material(
                        elevation: 5.0,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                        child: TextField(
                          // controller: TextEditingController(text: locations[0]),
                          cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          style: dropdownMenuItem,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Search Facilities",
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black38, fontSize: 16),
                              prefixIcon: Material(
                                elevation: 0.0,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                                child: Icon(Icons.search),
                              ),
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 25, vertical: 13)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 110,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              border: Border.all(width: 3, color: secondary),
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(facilitiesListMap[index]['logoText']),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  facilitiesListMap[index]['name'],
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: primary,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.location_on,
                      color: secondary,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(facilitiesListMap[index]['location'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: primary, fontSize: 13, letterSpacing: .3)),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.sports_tennis,
                      color: secondary,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(facilitiesListMap[index]['type'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: primary, fontSize: 13, letterSpacing: .3)),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: got this error "message": "The method 'fromMap' isn't defined for the type '_FacilitiesListScreenState'.\nTry correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromMap'."

Comment: @MUHAMADZULHILMI fist off, I didn't tell you to use just `fromMap`. That's what you seem to be doing. I said `Facilities.fromMap`. Secondly, I said that I can imagine that you might have that method in your `Facilities` class. I don't really know what that class looks like. Maybe you can share the code of your `Facilities` class

Comment: this is facilities.dart ..... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1idXEJMdrbyz4PK8H56o6lBNuWJWikHL8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @MUHAMADZULHILMI I believe your problem is that you have 2 different `facilitiesList`. One in FacilitiesListScreen and one in Facilities class. Just renaming the one in FacilitiesListScreen can maybe solve your problem

Comment: just renaming what ?

Comment: it works but i want that features that when user click the picture will go to next page ,like it show the facilities.dart by using facilites_details_screen.dart,do you want to see facilites_details_screen.dart ?

Comment: @MUHAMADZULHILMI sorry but I don't want to help more than I did. It's very tiresome to explain things to someone who has very little understanding of how things work. I hope you can figure it out on your own or that maybe someone else wants to help you.

Comment: Sorry im new to flutter ,okay thank for your efforts